# Overload method with number param

Tags: scala

I need two functions:

```
update(byte: Byte) {}
update(int: Int) {}
```

Now I want to update a byte and try to call it with `update(0x01)`, but `update(Int)` is called.

Is there a way to call `update(Byte)` in one line?

I mean without explicit byte value `val byte: Byte = 0x01; update(byte)`.

For example `update(0x01: Byte)`?

Comment: Cast the parameter to `Byte`?

Comment: update((byte)0x01)

Comment: In scala this would be update(0x01.toByte). Thanks!